# My htaccess files keep changing on all my wordpress websites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have two wordpress websites on my dedicated server, and the htaccess files of both websites keeps changing to default one and become 444 chmod.

Even after i fix it and put chmod 444 of mine few days later it changes again on both websites.

Could you please help me make the htaccess files impossible to be overwritten or edited no matter what?

I will appreciate any help,

Thank you

Comment: Is it a dedicated ROOT-Server or a dedicated MANAGED-Server? I suspect it is a managed server and the .htacces has been overwritten by a specific server configuration. You should ask you provider how to solve this.

Comment: root server Sir. I can enter myself the server

Comment: The weir thing is when i upgrade a plugin or wordpress version after few hours htaccess changes again

Comment: also these htaccess files only on root directory of my wordpress websites, other folders or sites are not affected.

Comment: Your site is probably infected: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191570/20963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by scanning my ubuntu server using clamAv through SSH. 
Here is the command line I used:

```
clamav -ril /home/user/clamav.txt
```

The results revealed a backdoor script embedded in one of my old themes which wasn't even activated. I deleted that old theme entirely and rebooted my server then the problem is gone.

> **Don't waste your time with a WordPress plugin to scan for malware or**
>   **backdoor because that is unlikely to locate any virus. Install ClamAV**
>   **into your server then scan. If nothing is detected yet?! Install**
>   **another anti similar to ClamAV until you succeed to locate the threat.**

Answer (score 0):

I find my infected file in one of the themes of wordpress, so you have two ways

1. LogIn to wordpress and delete all the new themes that you are not using.
2. Go to you your admin page go to folder: wp-content/themes/sydney/404.php
3. open it and if you see the virus code like if it has +xml or Rewrite wordpress etc delete it.
4. go through all the themes folder 404.php pages.
5. change your wp login user name and password.
6. delete all the infected .htaccess files/remove the infected code and monitor your website the regularly and check ur .htaccess file to make sure you don't get attacked again.